# Detecting new files in Azure blob and insert (call sp proc) that entry to azure sql

Tags: azure, events, blob, onchange

If the only job is to detect new file changes in a blob container what is the best way to accomplish this, Azure Function or ADF pipeline, logic app (at the end we call an sp_proc which inserts into a table if the record doesn't exists).In case of a failure for some reason we need some built in logging so that no file is missed at the end of the day if sql connection fails or so, audit needs to be granular / queryable etc to detect this.

Comment: The service you have named can all do the trick. Azure Function combined with an Event Grid Event trigger seems a logical choice to me.

Comment: There really is no "best" way - you'll need to choose the service(s) that's right for you. The only thing to be aware of, is that you'd need to use Event Grid to detect new/updated blobs. You can then take whatever action is right for your app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest the combination of BLOB container + ServiceBus + Azure Function + SQL.

You can,

- For every new BLOB created, generate a new message in ServiceBus Queue
- Create the Azure Function with ServiceBus's Queue Trigger
- Let the Azure Function insert the entry into SQL table

The main advantage here is that incase any failure with Azure Function to insert the SQL table entry due to any network, outage or code issue, the original message on ServiceBus message will not removed until configured retries attempted, also you have the dead-letter Queue option to handle delivery failures.

You can configure the ServiceBus Queue event subscription in the Events tab of the Storage Account.

[image]

Comment: Perfect, Thank you ;-)

Comment: Do you have a C# sample code for this Azure Function ?

Comment: Why the additional (relatively expensive) ServiceBus? Event Grid has also a retry mechanism and DL mechanism and can trigger the function directly using blob storage events.